# found BAD_CHARACTER in aggregation query (MongoDB/pymongo)

Tags: python, mongodb, pycharm, pymongo

I am trying to perform an aggregation on a MongoDB document using pymongo. I am also using PyCharm IDE

```
MongoDB version = 3.4.4
Pymongo version = 3.4.0
Python version = 3.5.2
```

I have a collection : PlayerDetails with a document looking like this:

```
{'jersey': '11', 
'height': '6-1', 
'displayName': 'Maurice Williams', 
'lname': 'Williams', 
'fname': 'Maurice', 
'_id': ObjectId('590137b105488b49ace349ac'), 
'team': 'IND'}

 {'jersey': '12', 
'height': '6-4', 
'displayName': 'Tom Brady', 
'lname': 'Brady', 
'fname': 'Tom',  
'_id': ObjectId('590137b105488b49ace34551'), 
'team': 'NE'}
```

I am writing a python code to join two documents by team. I have this following code:

Database.py code snippet:

```
import pymongo

class Dbase:
    def setupConnection(self):
        uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
        Mongoclient = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
        Mongoclient.drop_database('MongoProject')
        database = Mongoclient['MongoProject']
        return database
```

App.py code snippet:

```
import urllib.parse
import json
import pymongo
from Database import Dbase

def main():
    Dbase_Obj = Dbase()
    conn = Dbase_Obj.setupConnection()
    collectionPlayerDetl = conn['PlayerDetails']  


    ####select query using Join on both Player and Team details
    collectionPlayerDetl.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:{
            from:'TeamDetails',
            localField: "team",
            foreignField: "code",
            as:"team_descp"}
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "team_descp.id":0}
    }
    [![\]][1]][1])
```

on both queries I am attempting, I get a syntax error on $project and $lookup - "Statement Expected, found BAD_CHARACTER"

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like we just have to add quotes-

```
collectionPlayerDetl.aggregate([
{
"$lookup": {
"from":'TeamDetails',
"localField": 'team',
"foreignField": 'code',
"as":'CombinedDetails'
}
}])
```